# Match email addresses to Likes on a company page

Tags: facebook-like

so I've been tasked with producing a csv of customer information. One of the requested columns is to know if a particular customer has "Liked" us on Facebook.

Can this be done? If so, do I use FQL via the API? It seems as though Facebook keeps the email secret - so I'm not sure how I'd be able to match the user to Facebook.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean customers == app users?

Comment: Well, no, we're not using Facebook Connect. Customers are customers on their store - separate from Facebook. But they may have "Liked" a product on the store ... does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way programmatically (without screen scraping) to get a list of people who've liked you page.  Here's the page https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=PAGEID where up to the last 500 users are listed.

If you authenticate a user using Facebook Login, then you can determine if they've liked your page.  Or if you have a page tab application, you can check the signed_request for if the current viewer has liked.